# Ionic Storage on Android does not work when I have little storage space

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, storage

Ionic Storage on Android does not work when I have little storage space. How can I validate the space or an alternative?

How much is the minimum required by Ionic Storage, because other native applications if I can store things with little space?

Comment: I ran into the same problem, only after clearing 1gb or so, it started working. Did you find the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

The set method returns a promise that resolves when the key and value are set. I'm guessing it won't when there is too little space. What is too little diskspace? I think this depends on the device and the manufacturer. So there is no way telling.